# Equivalent of md5 hashing in linux commands

Tags: c, linux, hash, openssl, md5

I have the following code in C

```
u_char buf[64] = "hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha";
//Make MD5 hash over buffer
MD5_Init(&ctx);
MD5_Update(&ctx, buf, sizeof(buf));
MD5_Final(buf, &ctx);
```

`MD5_Init`, `MD5_Update` and `MD5_Final` are from openssl library.

The above code make a MD5 hash over the buffer `buf`.

I want to make the same thing with linux command using `md5sum`

```
$echo -n "hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha" | md5sum
```

but I did not get the same result

What is the equivalent of md5 hashing in linux commands?

Comment: What is the hash returned by openssl implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I did not use the same string lenght in the linux example I used string length 32 instead of 64. I get the same result

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `md5sum` is the equivalent.

`echo` prints out a new-line character. Try `echo -n hahaha.... | md5sum`.

Comment: In fact my test was with the -n I updated my question sorry for the typo

Comment: Sorry, I did not use the same string lenght in the linux example I used string length 32 instead of 64. I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Do 'echo -n' rather than 'echo', echo appends a newline so you're really hashing 'hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha\n'

Comment: In fact my test was with the -n I updated my question sorry for the typo

Comment: What system did you run that on?  According to the manpage, on non-GNU systems, you need to do `md5sum -b` to use binary mode, which is likely what C is doing.

Comment: Sorry, I did not use the same string lenght in the linux example I used string length 32 instead of 64. I get the same result